# Composed unique id in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Is possible to build a composed unique key in one attribute? I'm trying to build an attribute with segmented unique value, eg. "otherId" have length 10 and have two segments (5 characters for each one).

first register => otherId="1234500000"
second register => otherId="1234511111"

the full id is different but segmented, the first part is equal, then these ids would be detected as duplicated.

first register otherId="12345-00000"
second register otherId="12345-11111"

12345 is the common value, is possible build a composed key with these rules?

Comment: if you want independent logic based on segments, why keep them as a single key? You could just have each segment its own column(key) and join them to form the id?

Comment: Of corse, is a better way for this case, but if the ammount of segments is dynamical or it's higher?, eg. (10 segments), what is your recommendation?

Comment: even if there are 10 segments, it is easier to logically seperate them if you want individual segments to be "categorical" and perform operations on them. Otherwise, it will be highly difficult and error prone to manipulate the segments that are stored in one string by splitting

Comment: Ok, I agree with You, the logical processing is hardest in this case, thank You for the recommendation.